# In Visual Studio MFC can I have text in a combo box but get an int in the code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, combobox, mfc, visual-c++-6

I have a prefilled drop down set up as a combobox in MFC. The code needs a value between 0 and 15, but these values actually represent times. Is there a way to have the display of the combo box show the times (strings) but still return the integer value for the spot?

I could make a dropdown of string values, then use a switch statement to choose the int value based of the returned string value, but this seems like the kind of thing that might be built in already.

I'm quite new to MFC, mostly been stumbling my way through, so I may well have missed an obvious solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SetItemData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ekb53ey.aspx) to set an unsigned integer value for every item in the combo box.

The switch statement wouldn't work, since switch statements don't work on strings. You could use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` though.

Comment: I would not mix MFC collection by other collection ... I suggest to use CMap instead of std::map ...

Comment: @flaviu2 Mark's answer soesn't suggest mixing MFC collections with other collections. CCoboBox is not a collection but a wrapper for the WIN32 combo box. So using CMap or std::map doesn't metter here.

Comment: So this did work, but while testing things I seem to have found another way (that I'm an idiot for not trying earlier). I left the code calling for an int from the CComboBox, but went to the dialog in resource view and edited the properties of the box to list the values I wanted shown. This then showed the desired values but still output an integer when called. I'm not sure if one way is better or worse, but figured I'd mention that I did find a second way.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to convert the integer to string and then put in the combo box .

Put the following code in the OnInitDialog function



CComboBox* pCombo = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO);
CWnd* pComboEdit = pCombo->GetWindow(GW_CHILD);
if (pComboEdit != NULL)
    pComboEdit->ModifyStyle(0, ES_NUMBER);
((CEdit*)pComboEdit)->LimitText(2);

CString str;
for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
{
    str.Format(L"%d", i);
    pCombo->AddString(str);
}
```